# i can get out from canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

I use canvas to draw a foot, and i want to draw only 10s, but i can wait this time for the first time, but when i draw i continue to draw all time. I can't get out the drawing.
How can i get out the drawing ?
I give you my code to draw :

```js
const page = document.querySelector('body'); // définition du body, espace de surveillance souris
const divCorps = document.getElementById('test-1'); // définition de test-1, div à déplacée
var nIntervId = setInterval(drawFoot, 10000);
const canvas = document.querySelector('#myCanvas');
const width = 80; /*canvas.width;*/
const height = 80; /*canvas.height;*/
const tableToDraw = canvas.getContext('2d');
nIntervId = setInterval(drawFoot, 10000);

function drawFoot() {
  tableToDraw.strokeStyle = "black";
  tableToDraw.fillStyle = "orange";
  tableToDraw.beginPath();
  tableToDraw.moveTo(28, 30);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(40, 30, 40, 38, 30, 44);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(26, 50, 28, 56, 32, 60);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(36, 66, 54, 70, 32, 72);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(26, 76, 20, 72, 20, 70);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(18, 66, 20, 64, 18, 58);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(16, 52, 16, 52, 14, 48);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(12, 38, 12, 36, 18, 32);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(22, 30, 24, 30, 28, 30); // fin voute plantaire
  tableToDraw.moveTo(36, 16);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(40, 16, 40, 22, 38, 24);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(36, 28, 34, 28, 32, 24);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(32, 18, 34, 16, 36, 16); //fin orteil
  tableToDraw.moveTo(28, 18);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(31, 19, 30, 26, 26, 26);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(25, 25, 25, 24, 25, 22);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(25, 19, 26, 18, 28, 18); // fin 2eme doigt de pied
  tableToDraw.moveTo(20, 21);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(22, 19, 23, 21, 23, 23);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(23, 27, 21, 27, 20, 26);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(19, 24, 19, 23, 20, 21); //fin 3eme doigt de pied
  tableToDraw.moveTo(16, 26);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(16, 24, 17, 23, 18, 24);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(19, 25, 19, 28, 17, 28);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(16, 28, 16, 27, 16, 26); // fin 4eme doigt de pied
  tableToDraw.moveTo(14, 27);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(15, 27, 16, 28, 16, 29);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(16, 30, 15, 31, 14, 31);
  tableToDraw.bezierCurveTo(12, 30, 13, 27, 14, 27); //fin petit doigt de pied
  tableToDraw.stroke(); // fin du pied
  tableToDraw.fill();
  clearInterval(nIntervId);
//  reset
};
```

```html
<div id="text-1"></div>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: You're probably looking for [beginPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath).

Comment: Welcome to SO! It seems to work for me. What do you mean by "get out from the drawing" exactly? If you only want it to draw once, why create an interval? If you do want to repeatedly draw this foot, you should probably clear the canvas between frames so they don't overwrite each other. As it stands, you're creating an interval and stopping it after the first iteration. `setTimeout` may be more appropriate.

Comment: I want drawing this one every X secondes, then i try setTimeout and never clean the canvas. just when clean the canvas, i can activate a new drawing with waiting the X times? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: i found what i want. How can i put my code in comment?